# Javascript class variable scope using prototype

Tags: javascript, class, variables, scope, prototypejs

I'm writing a basic class using prototype.js in which some class vars are set when the class is initialised - the problem is that these variables aren't available to other methods within the class.

```
var Session = Class.create({
initialize: function(){
    // define defaults
    this.source = '';
},
shout: function(){
    alert(this.source);
}});
```

I know it's something to do with scope and I'm sure it's a fairly basic issue - all help appreciated!

Thanks, Adam

Comment: Thanks guys - my (non)working copy was a bit more full than the one above, which I hadn't realised works. I'll go back and start from here! Thanks for all your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested Your code. It works as far as I can tell. Maybe setting the variable to the empty string is throwing you off?

Answer (score 1):

looks right... and it works for me.

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    var s = new Session();
    s.shout();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?  I've tried a number of permutations and can't reproduce anything that looks like the problem you are reporting.